# Using requests library in on_failure or on_sucesss hook causes the task to retry indefinitely

Tags: concurrency, python-requests, celery, django-celery

This is what I have:

```
import youtube_dl # in case this matters

class ErrorCatchingTask(Task):
    # Request = CustomRequest
    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        # If I comment this out, all is well
        r = requests.post(server + "/error_status/") 
        ....

@app.task(base=ErrorCatchingTask, bind=True, ignore_result=True, max_retires=1)
def process(self, param_1, param_2, param_3):
    ...
    raise IndexError
    ...
```

The worker will throw exception and then seemingly spawn a new task with a different task id `Received task: process[{task_id}`
Here are a couple of things I've tried:

- Importing `from celery.worker.request import Request` and overriding `on_failure` and `on_success` functions there instead.
- `app.conf.broker_transport_options = {'visibility_timeout': 99999999999}`
- `@app.task(base=ErrorCatchingTask, bind=True, ignore_result=True, max_retires=1)`
- Turn off `DEBUG` mode
- Set logging to `info`
- Set `CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT` to false ([Can I use Python requests with celery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963260/can-i-use-python-requests-with-celery))
- `import requests as apicall` to rule out namespace conflict
- Money patch `requests` [Celery + Eventlet + non blocking requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315657/celery-eventlet-non-blocking-requests)
- Move `ErrorCatchingTask` into a separate file

If I don't use any of the hook functions, the worker will just throw the exception and stay idle until the next task is scheduled, which what I expect even when I use the hooks. Is this a bug? I searched through and through on github issues, but couldn't find the same problem. How do you debug a problem like this?

Django 1.11.16
celery 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

My problem was resolved after I used [grequests](https://pypi.org/project/grequests/)

In my case, celery worker would reschedule as soon as conn.urlopen() was being called in `requests/adapters.py`. Another behavior I observed was if I had another worker from another project open in the same machine, sometimes infinite rescheduling would stop. This probably was some locking mechanism that was originally intended for other purpose kicking in.

So this led me to suspect that this is indeed threading issue and after researching whether `requests` library was thread safe, I found some people [suggesting different things.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315657/celery-eventlet-non-blocking-requests). In theory, monkey patching should have a similar effect as using `grequests`, but it is not the same, so just use `grequests` or `erequests` library instead.

Celery Debugging instruction is [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/debugging.html)